# Install Moodle to subdomain with Softaculous via cPanel

Tags: redirects, subdomain, cpanel, moodle

I installed Moodle to a directory with Softaculous. Since it doesn't allow installing to a subdomain, after installing it I created a subdomain and pointed the destination (of the subdomain) to the previously created Moodle directory. Now when I go to the `subdomain.example.com` it says

> Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through "`http://example.com/moodle`" address, sorry. Please notify server administrator.

I must be doing something wrong, when installing it was very similar to [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19783/install-wordpress-on-your-own-server-with-softaculous/).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Installation instructions for one piece of software don't necessarily tell you anything about another. Also, the situation there isn't the same as what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is misleading. You're not installing to a sub-domain. You installed to a directory, and are now trying to access it *via* a sub-domain. This becomes important because Moodle checks that it's only accessed [via its configured address](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=194419#p847216), in your case `example.com/moodle`

First, try editing the `wwwroot` value in the config file to match your desired sub-domain. Since your host seems to provide a simple way to point a sub-domain to a directory, that'll probably fix things.

Worst case, further down in that thread is a code hack that might work for you. It seems to

Comment: Ok what I really meant I guess was, how do I install anything with softaculous to a subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out how to do it.

1. You need to create the subdomain
2. Once you are in softaculous (version I'm using [4.1.0]), choose whatever you need to install
3. Select which domain. If you created a subdomain correctly, then that will be listed.
4. Leave the directory blank and it will get installed to that subdomain.